# ruby on rails: how to input hash values in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Problem: I want to save address as hash, but I can not edit it in `/_form`. How to access key/values in hash `/_form` correctly?

I have a Client model:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :address, Hash
end
```

clients_controller:

```
def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(:name, {:address => [:street, :city]})
end
```

client/_form:

```
= simple_form_for(@client) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.simple_fields_for :address do |t|
    = t.input :city
    = t.input :street
  = f.button :submit
```

Must it be something like:

```
= t.input :address["city"]
= t.input :'address["city"]'', id: :start
```

Also, how can I assign default keys? Would something like this in `Client.rb` work?

```
store :address, accessors: [ :city, :address]
```

Comment: yes it will work. Please try once

Comment: Why don't you try it, see if it works, then ask for assistance if you get stuck?

Comment: they fields work for saving city and street, but when going into `edit` view, I do not see the saved values